# Windows drive not showing in ubuntu 18.04 file manager

Tags: partitioning, 18.04

I installed ubuntu 18.04LTS alongside windows. I created a partition for ubuntu installation. So I chose 1. boot drive as Windows boot manager 2. I did not create swap and home partition, instead mount the partition as root parition and click install.

So the problem is in Ubuntu file manager I am not able to see any of the windows drive. I have seen many videos saying mount drives and turn off fast boot option in windows. I did all of this already but I think these solution are for when we are seeing the windows drive but not able to access those drives. But in my case windows drive are not showing up in Ubuntu file manager.

Comment: Have you checked in "other locations"?

Comment: Yes...I checked there too